# SQLite request return nothing

Tags: android, database, sqlite

this is insert code

```
    for(int i = 0 ;pseudo.size() <= i; i++){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        String contact = (String) pseudo.get(i);
        values.put("pseudo", contact);
        values.put("adresse", "test");
        values.put("image", "test");
        values.put("ID", "5");
        dbwrite.insert("Contact", null, values);
    }
```

And this is read code

```
String[] retour = {
        "pseudo",
        "xmppadresse",
        "image", "ID"
        };
    Cursor cursor = dbread.query("Contact", retour, null, null, null, null, "pseudo");
    Log.d("debug", "populateWithInitialContacts: "+cursor.getCount());
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String pseudo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pseudo"));
        Log.d("debug", "getcontact: "+pseudo);
        listcontact.add(new Contact(pseudo));
    }
    cursor.close();
```

My request return nothing(It's my first time using database SQLite in Android)

Comment: what does `Log.d("debug", "populateWithInitialContacts: "+cursor.getCount());` print out?

Comment: @petey This log print "populateWithInitialContacts: 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0 ;pseudo.size() <= i; i++)
```

This is not how you iterate over lists. You probably want something like

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < pseudo.size(); i++)
```